# why can't I call php file with ajax in Cpanel?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to call php file with ajax, but it seems there's a bug to fix, but I can't find it.....

here's my button in html *(p.s $row["id"] is a variable represented article id)*

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger delete' data-info-id='<?php echo $row["id"];?>'>Delete</button>
```

and here's my ajax code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
        var info_id = $(this).data("info-id");
        var deleteUrl = "/delete.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: deleteUrl,
            data: { 'info-id': info_id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (results) {
                console.log(results);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's delete.php, just test if it receives the variables from ajax or not

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['info-id'];

$result = json_encode($id);

return $result;

?>
```

But I there's nothing showed in console.log

Hope someone can give me some advises to fix this!

Thanks

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json'); put this in your php code <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$id = $_POST['info-id'];

Comment: `return` != `echo`

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez I've just added it, but still can't work, it there any setting about ajax in cpanel i should've noticed?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you mean in the button data-info-id ?

Comment: No let me answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
return $result;
```

to

```
echo $result;
```

[return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) is for returning, [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is for echoing (printing).